# SQLLite Query - Android 11

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Following query doesn't seem to be working on Android 11, though that same had been working very well on Android 10 and below.  Just wonder if something has been cooked up in query or Android blocked things.

```
SELECT c.*, s.* FROM tb_contact c INNER JOIN tb_single_chat AS s ON c.id=s.localId LEFT JOIN tb_single_chat_detail AS cd ON s.sId=cd.schatId GROUP BY s.localId ORDER BY cd.id DESC
```

Comment: `SELECT c.*, s.*` with `GROUP BY s.localId` would not even run in other databases. SQLite allows it, but this does not mean that it is logically correct. It would return undefined rows in any case. If it seems that it worked previously then it is coincidental.

Comment: Wildcards were removed, still looks like those GROUP BY or ORDER BY is messed. i guess.

Comment: Nothing is messed. When you GROUP BY s.localId you can only select s.localId and also include aggregate functions like MIN(), MAX(), SUM() etc